# Pandas: Same indices for each column. Is there a better way to solve this?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for the lousy text in the question? I can't come up with a summarized way to ask this question.

I have a dataframe (variable df) such as the below:

```
df
```

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | m | nan | nan |
| 2 | n | nan | nan |
| 3 | b | nan | nan |
| 1 | nan | t | nan |
| 2 | nan | e | nan |
| 3 | nan | r | nan |
| 1 | nan | nan | y |
| 2 | nan | nan | u |
| 3 | nan | nan | i |

The desired output is:

| ID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | m | t | y |
| 2 | n | e | u |
| 3 | b | r | i |

I solved this by running the following lines:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for column in df.columns:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df[column].dropna()], join='outer', axis=1)
```

And then I figured this would be faster:

```
empty_dict = {}
for column in df.columns:
    empty_dict[column] = df[column].dropna()
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(empty_dict)
```

However, the dropna could represent a problem if, for example, there is a missing value in the rows that have the values to be used in each column. E.g. if df.loc[2,'A'] = nan, then that key in the dictionary will only have 2 values causing a misalignment with the rest of the columns. I'm not convinced.

I have the feeling pandas must have a builtin function that will do a better job and either of my two solutions. Is there? If not, is there any better way of solving this?

Comment: Your dataframe is the result of a `concat` operation on 3 dataframes?

Comment: no, a request to some api

Comment: Maybe you should deal with the problem upstream (upon receipt of data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you only need `groupby().first()`:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
   ID  A  B  C
0   1  m  t  y
1   2  n  e  u
2   3  b  r  i
```

Comment: wow, I tried all kind of things with groupby, first wasn't one of them

Answer (score 1):

Use `stack_unstack()` as suggested by @QuangHoang if `ID` is the index:

```
>>> df.stack().unstack().reset_index()
    A  B  C
ID         
1   m  t  y
2   n  e  u
3   b  r  i
```

You can use `melt` and `pivot`:

```
>>> df.melt('ID').dropna().pivot('ID', 'variable', 'value') \
      .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

   ID  A  B  C
0   1  m  t  y
1   2  n  e  u
2   3  b  r  i
```

Comment: it works, but I had to reset_index before melting as ID was the index of df

Comment: If `ID` is already the index, might just do `stack`, which saves you a `dropna()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang. Thanks. I updated my answer